# Unhandled exception Access violation writing location

Tags: c++, pointers, unhandled-exception

When I compile my program I get this unhandled exception that I don't understand or know how to fix.

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6DFF937FE in My
>   Code.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0x000002E07396F000.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Image.h"

Image readPPM(const char* file);
void writePPM(const Image &img, const char* file);

int main()
{

std::vector<Image> inputImages;
inputImages.resize(13);
Image *outputImage;

for (int x = 1; x < 14; x++)
{
    inputImages.push_back(Image(3264, 2448));
    inputImages[x] = readPPM(std::string("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_" + std::to_string(x) + ".ppm").c_str());
}

outputImage = new Image(3264, 2448);
outputImage->pixels = new Image::Rgb[3264, 2448];

for (int x = 0; x < 3264 * 2448; x++) {
    float sumR = 0.f;
    float sumG = 0.f;
    float sumB = 0.f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        sumR += inputImages[i].pixels[x].r;
        sumG += inputImages[i].pixels[x].g;
        sumB += inputImages[i].pixels[x].b;
    }

    outputImage->pixels[x].r = sumR / 13;
    outputImage->pixels[x].g = sumG / 13;
    outputImage->pixels[x].b = sumB / 13;
}


writePPM(*outputImage, "testPPM.ppm");

return 0;
}

Image readPPM(const char *filename)
{
    //Remove this cout to prevent multiple outputs
    std::cout << "Reading image ..." << std::endl;
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(filename, std::ios::binary);
    Image src;
    try {
        if (ifs.fail()) {
            throw("Can't open the input file - is it named correctly/is it in the right directory?");
    }
    std::string header;
    int w, h, b;
    ifs >> header;
    if (strcmp(header.c_str(), "P6") != 0) throw("Can't read the input file - is it in binary format (Has P6 in the header)?");
    ifs >> w >> h >> b;
    src.w = w;
    src.h = h;
    //std::cout << w << " " << h << std::endl;
    src.pixels = new Image::Rgb[w * h]; // this is throw an exception if bad_alloc 
    ifs.ignore(256, '\n'); // skip empty lines in necessary until we get to the binary data 
    unsigned char pix[3]; // read each pixel one by one and convert bytes to floats 
    for (int i = 0; i < w * h; ++i) {
        ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(pix), 3);
        src.pixels[i].r = pix[0] / 255.f;
        src.pixels[i].g = pix[1] / 255.f;
        src.pixels[i].b = pix[2] / 255.f;
    }
    ifs.close();
}
catch (const char *err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err);
    ifs.close();
}

//Confirm image read
//Delete this to prevent multiple lines output
std::cout << "Image read" << std::endl;
return src;
}

//Write data out to a ppm file
//Constructs the header as above
void writePPM(const Image &img, const char *filename)
{
//std::cout << filename << std::endl;
std::cout << "Writing image ..." << std::endl;
if (img.w == 0 || img.h == 0) { fprintf(stderr, "Can't save an empty image\n"); return; }
std::ofstream ofs;
try {
    ofs.open(filename, std::ios::binary); // need to spec. binary mode for Windows users 
    if (ofs.fail()) throw("Can't open output file");
    ofs << "P6\n" << img.w << " " << img.h << "\n255\n";
    //std::cout << "P6\n" << img.w << " " << img.h << "\n255\n";
    unsigned char r, g, b;
    // loop over each pixel in the image, clamp and convert to byte format
    for (int i = 0; i < img.w * img.h; ++i) {
        r = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::min(1.f, img.pixels[i].r) * 255);
        g = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::min(1.f, img.pixels[i].g) * 255);
        b = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::min(1.f, img.pixels[i].b) * 255);
        ofs << r << g << b;
    }
    ofs.close();
    //Confirm image write
    std::cout << "Image written" << std::endl;
}
catch (const char *err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err);
    ofs.close();
    }
}
```

Image.h

```
#pragma once
//*********************************************
//Image class to hold and allow manipulation of images once read into the 
code
//from https://www.scratchapixel.com/
//*********************************************
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstdio>

class Image
{
public:
    // Rgb structure, i.e. a pixel 
    struct Rgb
    {
        Rgb() : r(0), g(0), b(0) {}
        Rgb(float c) : r(c), g(c), b(c) {}
        Rgb(float _r, float _g, float _b) : r(_r), g(_g), b(_b) {}
        bool operator != (const Rgb &c) const
        {
            return c.r != r || c.g != g || c.b != b;
        }
        Rgb& operator *= (const Rgb &rgb)
        {
            r *= rgb.r, g *= rgb.g, b *= rgb.b; return *this;
        }
        Rgb& operator += (const Rgb &rgb)
        {
            r += rgb.r, g += rgb.g, b += rgb.b; return *this;
        }
        friend float& operator += (float &f, const Rgb rgb)
        {
            f += (rgb.r + rgb.g + rgb.b) / 3.f; return f;
        }
        float r, g, b;
    };

     Image() : w(0), h(0), pixels(nullptr) { /* empty image */ }
     Image(const unsigned int &_w, const unsigned int &_h, const Rgb &c = 
 kBlack) :
        w(_w), h(_h), pixels(NULL)
    {
        pixels = new Rgb[w * h];
        for (int i = 0; i < w * h; ++i)
            pixels[i] = c;
    }
    //copy constructor
    Image(const Image &im)
    {
        w = im.w;
        h = im.h;
        pixels = new Rgb[im.w * im.h];
        for (int i = 0; i < im.w * im.h; ++i)
            pixels[i] = im.pixels[i];
    }
    //copy assignment operator
    Image& operator=(const Image& other)
    {
        w = other.w;
        h = other.h;
        pixels = new Rgb[other.w * other.h];
        for (int i = 0; i < other.w * other.h; ++i)
             pixels[i] = other.pixels[i];

        return *this;

    }
    const Rgb& operator [] (const unsigned int &i) const
    {
        return pixels[i];
    }
    Rgb& operator [] (const unsigned int &i)
    {
        return pixels[i];
    }
    ~Image()
    {
        if (pixels != NULL) delete[] pixels;
        //delete[] pixels;
    }
    //unsigned int w, h; // Image resolution 
    int w, h; // Image resolution
    Rgb *pixels; // 1D array of pixels 
    static const Rgb kBlack, kWhite, kRed, kGreen, kBlue; // Preset colors 
};

const Image::Rgb Image::kBlack = Image::Rgb(0);
const Image::Rgb Image::kWhite = Image::Rgb(1);
const Image::Rgb Image::kRed = Image::Rgb(1, 0, 0);
const Image::Rgb Image::kGreen = Image::Rgb(0, 1, 0);
const Image::Rgb Image::kBlue = Image::Rgb(0, 0, 1);
```

Here's the code that appears to be causing the problem. When debugging it seems to be that there's something wrong with the pointers here:

```
outputImage->pixels[x].r = sumR / 13;
outputImage->pixels[x].g = sumG / 13;
outputImage->pixels[x].b = sumB / 13;
```

Sorry I can't really provide anything else to go on but I have never had an error like this before so I don't know where to start in fixing it.

Comment: What exactly does readPPM return?

Comment: `outputImage = new Image(3264, 2448);` then `outputImage->pixels = new Image::Rgb[3264, 2448];` seems like a design flaw here. Why didn't the constructor for Image create the buffer?

Comment: `resize` and `push_back` is an unhealthy combination. Did you mean `reserve`?

Comment: `inputImages[0]` till `inputImages[13]` are empty, their `pixels` members are `nullptr`. You got it with `resize(13)` and then continued to push images into the vector starting from 14.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand @S.M. can you suggest a fix?

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @newbie123 Remove the line `inputImages.resize(13);` or replace it with `inputImages.reserve(13);`

Comment: @newbie123 -- `inputImages.resize(13);` -- Then your next `for` loop does this on the last iteration:  `inputImages[13] = readPPM...`.  This is an out-of-bounds access.  Anything else after that line becomes a moot point, since you've already invoked undefined behavior.  Indices in C++ start at `0`, not `1`.  If you're trying to fake 1-based arrays, stop doing this.  Start your array indexing at 0.

Comment: When I do that I get a Debug error: Expression: Vector subscript out of range @S.M.

Comment: @newbie123 -- `Vector subscript out of range`.  That is because you resized the vector to hold 13 items, and your very first `for` loop attempts to access inputImages[13], which is out-of-bounds.  Indices range from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the number of entries.  Don't know how much simpler to state this.

Comment: @newbie123 Try loop x from 0 till 13, not from 1 till 14. And iterate i from 0 till 13 too, not till 12.

Comment: I have made the changes to iterators and removed inputImages.resize(13); and that now works without Vector subscript out of range. But I'm still getting the Unhandled exception error.

Comment: @newbie123 Do you not see the error here `new Image::Rgb[3264, 2448];`?

Comment: @S.M. No I'm afraid

Comment: @newbie123 Try to replace the comma with the asterisk.

Comment: Please learn [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) you will save yourself much pain

Comment: @newbie123 -- `new Image::Rgb[3264, 2448];` -- In your words or understanding, what does this do, or what is it supposed to do?   Have you seen any usage of `new []` in a book, tutorial, etc. looking like that line?

Comment: Why does the constructor for Image take rows and columns if it does not allocate the pixel buffer?

Comment: Hold up I think It will probably help If I copy in all the code

Comment: Edited OP to show everything

Comment: @newbie123 Advice -- Your copy/assignment operator for `Image` fails miserably if 1)  self-assignment is done and 2) if `new` throws an exception.  Use the `copy / swap` idiom instead.

Comment: In your loop you should be doing this:   `inputImages.push_back(readPPM(std::string("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_" + std::to_string(x) + ".ppm").c_str());`

Comment: Also delete this line it is both wrong and if it was correct it would leak memory unnecessarily since your constructor already allocates pixels: `outputImage->pixels = new Image::Rgb[3264, 2448];`

Comment: Also delete `inputImages.resize(13);`

Answer (score 0):

There's some level of bad here. But I believe at the core you meant to write:

```
inputImages[x] = Image(3264, 2448);
inputImages[x].pixels = readPPM(std::string("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_" + std::to_string(x) + ".ppm").c_str());
```

---

Stepping through your code:

- `std::vector<Image> inputImages` - Leaves `inputImages` with a size of 0
- `inputImages.resize(13);` - Leaves `inputImages` with a size of 13 default constructed `Image`s
- `inputImages.push_back(Image(3264, 2448));` - Increments the size of `inputImages` by 1 by adding a default image onto the tail end, ultimately increasing the size of `inputImages` to 26
- `inputImages[x] = readPPM(std::string("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_" + std::to_string(x) + ".ppm").c_str());` - Modifies one of the default constructed `Image`s in `inputImages`' [1 - 12] then finally modifies the first `Image(3264, 2448)` in `inputImages`

This means that at a minimum you have 13 `Image(3264, 2448)` objects that are never accessed. The 1<sup>st</sup> element that is accessed by the code in question, `inputImage[0]` is a default constructed `Image`. And unless `readPPM` returns an `Image` with an allocated `pixels` field, there are no `Images` in `inputImages` [1 - 12] range which can support access to their `pixels` field.